# API takes long to respond, as its a heavy application, how can I create a thread to get response quicker

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java

I've developed an API using SpringBoot 
but my API takes long to respond, as its a heavy application. 
So I'm planning to give a response with meaningful message immediately and then run the heavy application in the back ground .
Is anyone familiar with this scenario.

I have a SpringBootWebApplication class which has main()

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

}
```

---

Also have OnDemandController class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/run/lob")
public class OnDemandControllerForLob{


@RequestMapping(value="get",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public @ResponseBody String processOndemandService(@Context 
HttpServletRequest request,  @Context HttpServletResponse response) {


//here is a method call that takes lot of time to execute
OnDemand.processtherequest();

return response

}
}
```

Can someone please suggest me the best way to get response immediately and run the application logic (or the method that invokes the heavy java application in the back ground). The response i need is just a string saying "your request is served".

Comment: Take a look at [DeferredResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html) javadoc as your controller return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post, @EnableAsync is already applied.

Now the `OnDemand.processtherequest()` method must be public and marked with @Asnyc.

However, `OnDemand.processtherequest();` looks like a static method call (based on the name).  **This will not work.**  There must be a Spring managed bean with a non-static method.  If `OnDemand` is not in your control then create a wrapper bean which delegates to the static method.  For example:

```
@Service
public class OnDemandService {

    @Async
    public void processTheRequest() {
        OnDemand.processtherequest();
    }

}
```

And in the controller, autowire the service, and call the method.  The controller method will return immediately while the method marked as @Async will run in a different thread.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/run/lob")
public class OnDemandControllerForLob {

    @Autowired
    private OnDemandService onDemandService;

    @RequestMapping(value="get",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public @ResponseBody String processOndemandService(@Context 
    HttpServletRequest request,  @Context HttpServletResponse response) {

        //here is a method call that takes lot of time to execute
        // OnDemand.processtherequest();
          onDemandService.processTheRequest();

    return "your request is served";
    }
}
```